# Merge old and new XML file using C#

Tags: c#, xml, merge

For the last couple of weeks I've been trying to create a C# application that merges 2 XML files to a new XML file. On it's own this is not so difficult to do when you know the layout of the XML files, but in this case, I don't know the layout of the files. It needs to be 100% dynamic without naming tags in the code.

The application needs to merge the 2 files together on the following way. Tags in the old file are leading, the values of those tags need to be in the final result, however it can't have any duplicates in it. But if there are new tags in the new XML file, it needs to be added to the final XML file on the right place.

To show you what I mean exactly, I created the following example:

XML file 1:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="BaseAddress" value="http://HOSTNAME:8820/" />
    <add key="OIPServerUrl" value="http://HOSTNAME:4512/" />
    <add key="WFAddress" value="http://HOSTNAME:8804" />
    <add key="WFUser" value="USER" />
    <add key="WFPassword" value="" />
    <add key="SiteRoot" value="somepath" />
    <add key="AlternateImages" value="somepath" />
    <add key="DataFolder" value="somepath2222" />
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
  </appSettings>
  <!-- Non User configurable part -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="S4M.Gen.Services.OIPData">
        <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="S4M.Gen.Model.IOIPData" behaviorConfiguration="WebHttpJsonBehavior">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
      <service name="S4M.OIP.Factory.Services.CSDMService">
        <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Base.Model.ServiceContracts.IDMService" behaviorConfiguration="WebHttpJsonBehavior">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
      <service name="S4M.WebServerService.StaticFileService">
        <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="web" contract="S4M.WebServerService.IStaticFileService">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding contentTypeMapper="Base.Service.ServiceContracts.RawMapper, Base.Service" />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="webHttpJson" type="Base.Service.ServiceContracts.WebHttpJsonElement, Base.Service" />
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="WebHttpJsonBehavior">
          <webHttpJson />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

XML file 2:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="BaseAddress" value="http://HOSTNAME:8820/" />
    <add key="OIPServerUrl" value="http://HOSTNAME:4512/" />
    <add key="WFAddress" value="http://HOSTNAME:8804" />
    <add key="WFUser" value="USER" />
    <add key="WFPassword" value="" />
    <add key="SiteRoot" value="somepath" />
    <add key="AlternateImages" value="somepath" />
    <add key="DataFolder" value="somepath" />
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
    <add key="RedirectCode" value="TemporaryRedirect"/> <!-- NEW tag -->
  </appSettings>
  <!-- Non User configurable part -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="S4M.Gen.Services.OIPData">
        <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="S4M.Gen.Model.IOIPData" behaviorConfiguration="WebHttpJsonBehavior">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
      <service name="S4M.OIP.Factory.Services.CSDMService">
        <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Base.Model.ServiceContracts.IDMService" behaviorConfiguration="WebHttpJsonBehavior">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
      <service name="S4M.WebServerService.StaticFileService">
        <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="web" contract="S4M.WebServerService.IStaticFileService">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding contentTypeMapper="Base.Service.ServiceContracts.RawMapper, Base.Service" />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="webHttpJson" type="Base.Service.ServiceContracts.WebHttpJsonElement, Base.Service" />
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="WebHttpJsonBehavior">
          <webHttpJson />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Final result:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="BaseAddress" value="http://HOSTNAME:8820/" />
    <add key="OIPServerUrl" value="http://HOSTNAME:4512/" />
    <add key="WFAddress" value="http://HOSTNAME:8804" />
    <add key="WFUser" value="USER" />
    <add key="WFPassword" value="" />
    <add key="SiteRoot" value="somepath" />
    <add key="AlternateImages" value="somepath" />
    <add key="DataFolder" value="somepath2222" />
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
    <add key="RedirectCode" value="TemporaryRedirect"/> <!-- NEW tag -->
  </appSettings>
  <!-- Non User configurable part -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="S4M.Gen.Services.OIPData">
        <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="S4M.Gen.Model.IOIPData" behaviorConfiguration="WebHttpJsonBehavior">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
      <service name="S4M.OIP.Factory.Services.CSDMService">
        <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Base.Model.ServiceContracts.IDMService" behaviorConfiguration="WebHttpJsonBehavior">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
      <service name="S4M.WebServerService.StaticFileService">
        <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="web" contract="S4M.WebServerService.IStaticFileService">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding contentTypeMapper="Base.Service.ServiceContracts.RawMapper, Base.Service" />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="webHttpJson" type="Base.Service.ServiceContracts.WebHttpJsonElement, Base.Service" />
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="WebHttpJsonBehavior">
          <webHttpJson />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The code that I have so far is the following:

```
 XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\1.config");
 XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\2.config");

 XDocument newdoc = new XDocument();


 var query1 = from el
       in doc2.Elements().Except(doc1.Elements())
       select el;
 var query2 = from el
       in doc1.Elements().Except(doc2.Elements())
       select el;

       var query = query2.Except(query1);

 foreach (var item in query)
 {
      newdoc.Add(item);

      Console.WriteLine(item);
 }
 newdoc.Save(@"C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\new.config");
 Console.ReadLine();
```

I've been working on this for quite some time, but I can't seem to figure it out. Can someone help me?

Comment: Completeley different xmls. And hard to read from final xml, what do you want to merge? appsettings? services? behaviours? Anyway forget it. i wouldn't answer this question if you had posted the correct xmls at the beginning.

Comment: assumption that come after looking at your original sample xml is xmls input only have one level depth (root > element, not root > element > subelement > ...). My answer won't work with recent xmls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\1.config");
XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\2.config");
var query1 =
            doc2.Root.Elements().Where(
                o => !doc1.Root.Elements().Select(p => p.Name.LocalName).Contains(o.Name.LocalName));
foreach (var item in query1)
{
    doc1.Root.Add(item);
}
doc1.Save(@"C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\new.config");
```

Comment: I have tried the solution but it doesn't add any new tags from doc2.
But the data from doc1 is added correctly

Comment: I tried this with sample input you posted and the output is the same as your *Final Result* except elements order is different. Try to check content of your files (1.config & 2.config) maybe?